# Only declare variable if doesn't exist yet in the initialization of a class

Tags: python, class

I'm working for the first time with OOP in a python project. I have 3 classes: PRA, GDB and XLS.

```
PRA = Main Class
GDB = Responsible for control databases
XLS = Responsible for control xls(x)
UserInput = Responsible for validate user input
```

How i'm doing:

PRA:

```
class PRA(GDB, XLS, UserInput):

    __init__():
      self.gdb_file, self.xls_file = self.ask_questions() # <--- ask_questions is inside the UserInput class.
      self.do_something()
```

XLS:

```
class XLS:

  do_something():
    print(self.xls_file)

  __init__(self, xls_file):
     self.xls_file = xls_file
```

GDB:

```
class GDB:

  __init__(self, gdb_file):
     self.gdb_file = gdb_file
```

I would like to know if is a bad practice to initialize the gdb_file and xls_file inside the PRA.**init**, and if not, how can i run the initialization of self.xls_file and self.xls_gdb only in the PRA?

Comment: Why would it be bad practice? The `__init__` method is precisely meant for such initialisations.

Comment: Because i'm initializing the self.gdb_file and self.xls_file in two places: inside the PRA , GDB and XLS classes...

Comment: Well, you may say that it is a bit ugly that you have to type the same code several times. But remember that just because `PRA` inherits from `XLS` and `GDB`, only `PRA.__init__` gets called when you instantiate a `PRA` instance.

Comment: You could call `XLS.__init__` and `GDB.__init__` explicitly from within `PRA.__init__` if you would like `PRA`-instances to use the initialisation codes from these classes.

Comment: Is this a good practice jmd_dk?

Comment: What would be the "python way", i mean?

Comment: @CantFindMe have you considered [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)?

Comment: @CantFindMe the "good practice" (and pythonic way - but that would be true in any OOPL) here is to **not** use inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but more of an example of code reuse. I'm not sure if this is super Pythonic, though. Anyhow, take a look at this example:

```
import inspect

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 2

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        for super_class in inspect.getmro(type(self))[1:]:
            super_class.__init__(self)

c = C()
print(c.a, c.b)
```

Comment: Trying to be "smart" that way only leads to maintenance nightmares (been here, done that). And this won't solve the problem of uncompatible parent classes constructors anyways.<g>

Comment: Agreed, the cases where this is the right solution are fairly limited. It is a nice showoff of Python's dynamic abilities, though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

A bit OT but you may want to think twice about your class names... They are really terrible.

Now wrt/ your question... Technically, the way to handle proper initialisation of a parent class is to call it's initialiser from the child class, ie:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        super(Child, self).__init__(name)
        self.age = age
```

You can also explicitly name the parent class, ie:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        Parent.__init__(self, name)
        self.age = age
```

but it has a couple drawbacks, like harcoding the parent class in the call (so you have two or more places to edit if you change the parent class), and, more important, not taking care of proper resolution of the "diamond" problem in multiple inheritance (ie D child of B & C, B child of A, C child of A).

Actually, the only reason to *not* use `super()` would be when parent classes constructor are not compatible, but this is a **huge** design smell - if you have two or more parent classes that are not compatible, then you're certainly not using inheritance the right way. And that's actually the case in your example: your "main" class "is" not a "Database controller", it **uses** a Database controller instead, so you want to use composition, not inheritance

```
class ServiceA(object):
    # code here

class ServiceB(object):
    # code here

class Main(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        self.arg1 = arg1  
        self.service_a = ServiceA(arg2)
        self.service_b = ServiceB(arg3)

    def run(self):
        something = self.service_a.ask(question)
        self.service_b.do_something_with(something)
```

Also you may want to avoid user interactions and costly resource acquisitions in constructors... Better use an entry point method for the first case (like `app = MyApp(params)`; app.run()`) and lazy initialization for the second case (wait until you need the resource to acquire it, use a private attribute as cache an a public property that will take care of acquisition on first access).

[edit]

Someone suggested a dirty hack based on introspection, ie:

```
import inspect

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 2

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        for super_class in inspect.getmro(type(self))[1:]:
            super_class.__init__(self)

c = C()
print(c.a, c.b)
```

This is **definitly not** something to do.

If all your parent classes have compatible constructors and properly use `super` calls, then all you have to do is using `super` instead:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        self.a = "a"

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.b = "b"

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__()
        self.c = "c"

c = C()
print c.a, c.b, c.c
```

This also takes care of the "diamond inheritance" problem by calling parent classes in the right order:

```
class D(C, A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(D, self).__init__()
        self.d = "d"

d = D()
print "d : ", d.a, d.b, d.c, d.d
```

Note that unless only one of the parent classes is a "proper" class (with state) and all other are mixin classes (stateless classes that only add functionalities), multiple inheritance is more often than not a design smell (as well as a maintainance hell). Since Python doesn't use static typing, inheritance is mostly used for implementation inheritance, and for a lot of cases composition/delegation (or just plain composition as in the OP case) is a better solution than implementation inheritance.